# Neo4j upgrade to 3.0 OSX

Tags: macos, neo4j, upgrade

I am trying to start upgraded Neo4j 3.0.1 first time in my Mac OSX 10.9.5 machine. It gives a message box

> Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable
>   automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter
>   "dbms.allow_format_migration=true"

How I can give configuration parameters, when starting the server? Maybe the commands should be

```
cd /Applications
./Neo4j Community Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/neo4j-shell dbms.allow_format_migration=true`
```

but `bash` says

> ./Neo4j Community Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/neo4j-shell
>   dbms.allow_format_migration=true: No such file or directory

Comment: You have to put this line into Neo4j configuration file (ie. conf/neo4j.conf), and then start your server.

Comment: One may need to download the tar version (not the dmg) for this to work